# i want to make home automation using enterance door autoamte light on off

Tags: arduino, sensors

I want to make home automation system for my final year project. One module of my project is light ON OFF on entrance, for that purpose I used IR sensor but the range of IR sensor is 20cm which is not suitable for my project, i need minimum 4 feet ranger to detect the human to turn ON OFF light. anyone suggest me to which sensor is best for that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You csn use what's called [human sensor](https://a.aliexpress.com/_vm7AMT), it is very sensitive and provide the on off signal you need, low cost, easy to use ans small enough to fit inside any sensor enclosure.